How "used to" is really used
Modals "could, would, might" can be used with "be" + the continuous form of a verb referring to ongoing past actions.
Back in the days before TV, the entire family could | would | might be sitting around the radio for hours in the evening.
What if instead of "could,would,might"  I would use " used to". Could I use this structure with "be +the continuous form"?

They "used to sit round the radio", not "used to be sitting round the radio". Try not to use 'continuous' more than necessary. It's in the past, and even in the present is overused in Indian English.

... moreover in my mind, the sit round I posted seems more active than sitting round despite the continuous tense.

@WeatherVane, "sit round" seems more used in UK... "sit around" is the phrase of OP, and the more common usage today, at least in NA.
